# Does composer have an official docker image?

Tags: php, shell, docker, composer-php

I've been running composer install in a shell script when I build a docker image, but that along with a lot of other calls is making my build super slow and I'm wondering if there's a better/different way to go about this.

Comment: Where is it slow? More details please. Php composer dependencies are tipical an slow thing. You need to arrange the Dockerfile commands in a way to maximize the layer caching reuse

Comment: Not sure what you think a Composer image would do - the slowness is in fetching the dependencies your app needs *using* Composer. We use https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo to speed that up a bit... and make sure `composer.lock` is present, that'll speed things up immensely.

Comment: Yep, there are 2 official images on Docker Hub. One from [Composer/Composer](https://hub.docker.com/r/composer/composer/) and other one from [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @janshair-khan points out, there are two images. But composer/composer is deprecated, as you can see from the [source repository](https://github.com/RobLoach/docker-composer). So I suggest you use the [Docker Official Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer/) for composer.